# Can I configure my Linux box as a virtual network switch for my VMs? Should I?

Tags: switch, network, networking

[image: network diagram]

So I have two computers, one Windows machine with wifi enabled and one linux box without wifi. My working connection is I have an ethernet cable going between both my PCs, with Windows 10 being the gateway at 192.168.137.1/24 and my Linux box getting 192.168.137.9. In this setup, the Windows 10 PC acts as a router using NAT out to the router. This works just fine. But I want my VMs inside my Linux box to be able to connect directly to the 192.168.137.0/24 subnet without having to do any sort of NAT in my Linux box, since I want my Windows 10 PC to be able to directly talk to my VMs.

For the VMs, I'm using QEMU in a Linux Mint box. I've tried using bridged mode, but at this point I feel like I need some advice on whether or not this is even a good idea to begin with. Could bridged mode work?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].